# How to Trigger an MahApps animations manually

Tags: wpf, animation, mahapps.metro

I'am using MahApps.Metro in WPF application. The animations are very beautiful like the animations of TabControl changing tabs.

i want to animate some element (e.g a Wrap Panel) manually.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Got it, i need to envolve my elements in a MetroContentControl element and call the Reload() method of the MetroContentControl.